# Server default collation change or not change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, configuration, collation

The default collation of our new server is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. However the collation of the other databases which are used as the source to migrate data into the target databases on this server are `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

To avoid getting the error while we load data from database 1 (collation:`Latin1_General_CI_AS`) to database 2 (collation:`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`), I changed the collation of database 2 (the target database) to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

However I'm wondering if it might any side-affect? 
What is the reason that the server default collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`? Is it any better than other collation, in terms of performance, etc?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out this issue and share it here, in case someone needs it in future.

The default collation setting is determined by the server locale. For most English speaking countries is it : `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

If the server locale setting has been left as default which is English (United States), the collation at time of MS SQL Management Studio would be set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

[image]
You can check the collation for each local in the following url:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx

Comment: I ran through the setup installer for SQL 2008 r2 Express and Standard edition and the default value for collation is certainly "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" .  If you want "SQL_General_CI_AS" , you would have to change the default config value during setup.